# How to allow people from external network to access my Node.js app via IP address?

Tags: node.js

I tried Google for the last 3 days and also found most of the StackExchange answers for LAN. I found no solution to enable people to access my app from an external network.

I have already enabled access for Node.js to connect anywhere in the internet in my firewall, which should not be a concern, but I am not sure.

Comment: You can use ngrok tool or simply deploy your application into any free hsoting service like DigiticalOcen or heorku

Comment: @AhmedRebai Bit overkill. A simple port-forward rule on the router/NAT will make it public to the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to your router and set a port-forward-rule

  - Set the ip to your local ip of your computer
  - Set the port to the port your app is running on
- Give your mates your public (external) ip address

Thats it. Your router will forward all traffic from the outsite to the set port on your local computer. No special software needed.

You can google for how to setup port-forwarding for every brand online. In most cases its self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been the most helpful.

Comment: Happy that you managed to set it up. Little advanced tip: If you can set destination and source port: Set the source port to 80 and the destination to your apps port (e.g. 52334). That way visitors can visit your app via http://yourip without any port. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tunneling library, such as https://ngrok.com/
This will give you a URL where anybody can access your APIs online.

Answer (score 0):

If your nodejs app ( http server or other ) behind the `NAT` like a home `DSL` link and there's no valid ip address assigned to your machine, You need to do `Destination NAT/PAT` which known as `virtual server` in most DSL modems. Also you can use online DNAT tools like no-ip or others too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I need to study about 'Destination NAT/PAT' as I am not aware of it.